# Fetching translation object based on user's company

Tags: i18next, react-i18next

I'm currently trying to use react-i18next for the following use case: an application built for different companies and targeted toward the user company. The company name for users differs but they will reuse the same UI components. The translations object will look like this:

```
{
  "companyX": {
    "homeFeature": {
      "title": "Sint est in mollit ",
      "description": "Incididunt quis mollit id excepteur amet ipsum."
    }
  },
  "companyY": {
    "homeFeature": {
      "title": "Dolor esse eiusm ut."
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried this to load the specific key in the translation JSON (eg: companyX) and added it to the `i18next` config and it works.

```
const translationsJson = {
  en: {
    translation: en["companyX"],
  },
  de: {
    translation: de["companyX"],
  },
};
```

I would like to know what is the correct way to load the resource based on the user's company.

I'd be happy to hear your thoughts on that! Let me know if I left things unclear or can be of any assistance!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

This will init i18next with the resources for the company specified in the company variable.

```
const translationsJson = {
  en: {
    translation: en["companyX"],
  },
  de: {
    translation: de["companyX"],
  },
};

const company = "companyX";

const i18n = i18next.init({
  lng: "en",
  resources: {
    en: {
      translation: translationsJson.en.translation[company],
    },
    de: {
      translation: translationsJson.de.translation[company],
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The creators of i18next do offer a nice setup that may cover your needs.

You can create company-specific projects based on your main project. All translations are anticipated for the company-specific project and can be overridden, if necessary.

But the anticipated translations are not just copied, so in case you need to correct a translation in your main project, it will be automatically populated to your company-specific projects, if not overridden.

More information about this setup can be found [here](https://docs.locize.com/more/multi-tenant).